# How do I force my Azure pipeline to build with .NET 5.0?

Tags: azure-pipelines, .net-5

We have started migrating some of our libraries to net 5.0, and need to build these in an Azure pipeline.

Our pipelines are set up to use a specific SDK version, using the step "Use .NET Core SDK". This step fails when we specify version 5.0.101.

[image]

It fails with this error

> Tool to install .NET Core SDK version 5.0.101.
> ##[error]Failed to download or parse releases-index.json with error: {"errno":"ENOTFOUND","code":"ENOTFOUND","syscall":"getaddrinfo","hostname":"dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net","host":"dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net","port":443}
> Finishing: Use .NET Core SDK 5.0.101

Comment: Looks like a networking issue in Azure, tbh. The .NET install task needs to find a `releases-index.json` file via the network to find out what versions are available and where to get them, but the machine can't resolve or connect to that host.

Comment: Hi @Torben Nielsen, Which agent are you using? Hosted agent or self-hosted agent? It seems an event issue, could you try it again and then share the result here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is similar to [GitHub issue #10969](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10969). It has something to do with internal GitHub repo/url. This is because the [version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops#task-inputs) which we specify in the task is searched in **`releases-index`** file, which is accessible to public as well:

[image]

**[releases-index:](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/releases-index.json)**

```
{
    "releases-index": [
        {
            "channel-version": "5.0",
            "latest-release": "5.0.1",
            "latest-release-date": "2020-12-08",
            "security": false,
            "latest-runtime": "5.0.1",
            "latest-sdk": "5.0.101",
            "product": ".NET",
            "support-phase": "current",
            "releases.json": "https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release-metadata/5.0/releases.json"
        },
        {
            "channel-version": "3.1",
            "latest-release": "3.1.10",
            "latest-release-date": "2020-11-10",
            "security": false,
            "latest-runtime": "3.1.10",
            "latest-sdk": "3.1.404",
            "product": ".NET Core",
            "support-phase": "lts",
            "eol-date": "2022-12-03",
            "releases.json": "https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release-metadata/3.1/releases.json"
        },
        {
            "channel-version": "3.0",
            "latest-release": "3.0.3",
            "latest-release-date": "2020-02-18",
            "security": false,
            "latest-runtime": "3.0.3",
            "latest-sdk": "3.0.103",
            "product": ".NET Core",
            "support-phase": "eol",
            "eol-date": "2020-03-03",
            "releases.json": "https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release-metadata/3.0/releases.json"
        },
        {
            "channel-version": "2.1",
            "latest-release": "2.1.23",
            "latest-release-date": "2020-10-13",
            "security": false,
            "latest-runtime": "2.1.23",
            "latest-sdk": "2.1.811",
            "product": ".NET Core",
            "support-phase": "lts",
            "eol-date": "2021-08-21",
            "releases.json": "https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release-metadata/2.1/releases.json"
        },
        {
            "channel-version": "2.2",
            "latest-release": "2.2.8",
            "latest-release-date": "2019-11-19",
            "security": true,
            "latest-runtime": "2.2.8",
            "latest-sdk": "2.2.207",
            "product": ".NET Core",
            "support-phase": "eol",
            "eol-date": "2019-12-23",
            "releases.json": "https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release-metadata/2.2/releases.json"
          },
        {
            "channel-version": "2.0",
            "latest-release": "2.0.9",
            "latest-release-date":"2018-07-10",
            "security": true,
            "latest-runtime": "2.0.9",
            "latest-sdk": "2.1.202",
            "product": ".NET Core",
            "support-phase": "eol",
            "eol-date": "2018-10-01",
            "releases.json": "https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release-metadata/2.0/releases.json"
        },
        {
            "channel-version": "1.1",
            "latest-release": "1.1.13",
            "latest-release-date": "2019-05-14",
            "security": true,
            "latest-runtime": "1.1.13",
            "latest-sdk": "1.1.14",
            "product": ".NET Core",
            "support-phase": "eol",
            "eol-date": "2019-06-27",
            "releases.json": "https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release-metadata/1.1/releases.json"
        },
        {
            "channel-version": "1.0",
            "latest-release": "1.0.16",
            "latest-release-date": "2019-05-14",
            "security": true,
            "latest-runtime": "1.0.16",
            "latest-sdk": "1.1.14",
            "product": ".NET Core",
            "support-phase": "eol",
            "eol-date": "2019-06-27",
            "releases.json": "https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release-metadata/1.0/releases.json"
        }
    ]
}
```

And, if you check, `https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release-metadata/5.0/releases.json` is accessible publicly as well. Hence, I am of the conviction that the URL mentioned internally is wrong and hence the agent throws **NOT FOUND** error.

In this case, I would recommend you to reopen [**Issue #10969**](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10969) and inform the product team.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the SDK 5.0.101 isn't yet available in Azure Pipelines, as you can see in the accepted values: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/releases-index.json

If you just want to use 5.0, use:

```yaml
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '5.x'
```

Comment: Ok. I did not know that syntax. So you can just put 5.x and will grab the newest version? Anyway I get the same error "##[error]Failed to download or parse releases-index.json with error: {"errno":"ENOTFOUND","code":"ENOTFOUND","syscall":"getaddrinfo","hostname":"dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net","host":"dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net","port":443}"

Comment: Well, I'm using that exact syntax in a few pipelines and it's working without any issues (I actually copy-pasted the lines), so there might be something else going on there @TorbenNielsen.